# Does SP 2010 have any support for taxonomy update workflows?

Tags: workflow, managed-metadata, taxonomy

Does SP 2010 have any support for taxonomy update workflows?
Or if not directly, is it possible to develop something like that using the Sharepoint API?
What would be needed:

- taxonomy change proposals
- notifying interested persons about proposed taxonomy changes
- accepting / rejecting the changes
- finding the files to be affected by proposed changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge it doesn't existing, but it would be quite easy to build ontop of a standard list where you configure the workflow, and then upon approval you can from you list event receiver add the new taxonomy data or change the existing taxonomy.